# VSTO: Why is OfficeRibbon.Context null?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto, ribbon

I'm developing my first Word 2007 addin, and I've added an OfficeRibbon to my project. In a button-click handler, I'd like a reference to either the current `Word.Document` or `Word.Application`.

I'm trying to get a reference via the `OfficeRibbon.Context` property, which the documentation says should refer to the current `Application` object. However, it is always `null`.

Does anyone know either

a) if there is something I need to do to make `OfficeRibbon.Context` appear correctly populated?
b) if there is some other way I can get a reference to the Word Application or active Word Document?

Notes:

- I'm using VS2008 SP1
- The ribbon looks like it has initialized fine: The ribbon renders correctly in Word; I can step the debugger through both the constructor and the OnLoad members; Button click handlers execute correctly.
- Here's [the online help for this property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.officeribbon.context.aspx?ppud=4);

> **OfficeRibbon.Context Property**
>
> `C#`
>   `public Object Context { get; internal set; }`
>
> An Object that represents the Inspector window or application instance that is associated with this OfficeRibbon object.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> In Outlook, this property refers to the Inspector window in which this OfficeRibbon is displayed.
>
> In Excel, Word, and PowerPoint, this property returns the application instance in which this OfficeRibbon is displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also encountered this problem while creating an Excel 2007 AddIn using VS2008 SP1.  The workaround I used was to store the Application in an `internal static` property in the main AddIn class and then reference it in the event handler in my ribbon:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    internal static Application Context { get; private set; }

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Context = Application;
    }
    ...
}

public partial class MyRibbon : OfficeRibbon
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        DoStuffWithApplication(ThisAddIn.Context);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try referencing the document with:

```
Globals.ThisDocument.[some item]
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhczd18c.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Get it from:

`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application`

Answer (score 1):

While I dont know much about changes in Office 2007 word object model, here is my explanation using VBA knowledge.

Application is a globally available object.
Also, Application.ActiveDocument should get you handle to the current document.

Speculating: How are you trying to add the ribbon?